# Evaluate: $\int \tan^5 (x). \sec (x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate: $\int \tan^5 (x). \sec (x) dx$

My Attempt:
$$=\int \tan^5 (x).\sec (x).dx$$
$$=\int \tan^4 (x).\sec (x).\tan (x) dx$$
$$=\int (\sec^2 (x)-1)^2 .\sec (x).\tan (x) dx$$
$$=\int (\sec^4 (x)-2\sec^2 (x)+1).\sec (x).\tan (x) dx$$

Comment: Why did you stop? You were doing fine.

Comment: @bof, what to do next?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{d}{dx}\sec (x)=\sec (x) \tan (x)$, try using your second to last step and setting $u=\sec (x)$, note that you have $du=\sec (x) \tan (x)dx$ waiting on the right. What does the rest become, can you integrate that?

Answer (score 1):

It usually helps to convert to $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$.

$$\begin{aligned}\int \tan^5(x)\sec(x)dx &= \int \frac{\sin^5(x)}{\cos^6(x)}dx \\
&=-\int \frac{(1-\cos^2(x))^2}{\cos^6(x)}(-\sin(x))dx \\
&=-\int \frac{(1-u^2)^2}{u^6}du
\end{aligned}$$
where $u=\cos (x)$. I'll leave the remaining steps to you since they're fairly easy.